# insert into after CTE, mySql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, procedure

I'm writing a procedure, using with to generate a table, then make an insert passing the fields of this table as a value, but mysql is returning a syntax error in the insert, does anyone have any idea what it is?

```
WITH origem AS (
    SELECT
        cnpj,
        MAX(nome_empresa)                          AS nome_empresa,
        SUM(qtd_documentos)                        AS qtd_documentos,
        codigo_uf_emitente,
        MAX(nome_uf_emitente)                      AS nome_uf_emitente,
        codigo_cidade_emitente,
        MAX(nome_cidade_emitente)                  AS nome_cidade_emitente,
        codigo_uf_destinatario,
        MAX(nome_uf_destinatario)                  AS nome_uf_destinatario,
        codigo_cidade_destinatario,
        MAX(nome_cidade_destinatario)              AS nome_cidade_destinatario,
        SUM(qtd_produtos)                          AS qtd_produtos,
        SUM(valor_total_frete)                     AS valor_total_frete,
        SUM(valor_total_nfe)                       AS valor_total_nfe,
        _ano                                       AS ano,
        _mes                                       AS mes
    FROM
        dataset_nfe_transportadoras_diario
    WHERE
        ano     = _ano
        AND mes = _mes
    GROUP BY
        cnpj,
        codigo_uf_emitente,
        codigo_cidade_emitente,
        codigo_uf_destinatario,
        codigo_cidade_destinatario
)
INSERT INTO dataset_nfe_transportadoras_mensal(
    cnpj,
    nome_empresa,
    codigo_uf_emitente,
    nome_uf_emitente,
    codigo_cidade_emitente,
    nome_cidade_emitente,
    codigo_uf_destinatario,
    nome_uf_destinatario,
    codigo_cidade_destinatario,
    nome_cidade_destinatario,
    qtd_documentos,
    qtd_produtos,
    valor_total_nfe,
    valor_total_frete,
    mes,
    ano
)
```

my sqlcode is it

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? They each have different implementations for CTE features, and they have different limitations. You should stop considering MariaDB as compatible with MySQL. It isn't anymore. There are enough differences that you should treat MariaDB as a wholly different product.

Comment: Hello Bill, my current bank is MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the CTE as SELECT

```
INSERT INTO dataset_nfe_transportadoras_mensal
WITH origem AS (
    SELECT
        cnpj,
        MAX(nome_empresa)                          AS nome_empresa,
        SUM(qtd_documentos)                        AS qtd_documentos,
        codigo_uf_emitente,
        MAX(nome_uf_emitente)                      AS nome_uf_emitente,
        codigo_cidade_emitente,
        MAX(nome_cidade_emitente)                  AS nome_cidade_emitente,
        codigo_uf_destinatario,
        MAX(nome_uf_destinatario)                  AS nome_uf_destinatario,
        codigo_cidade_destinatario,
        MAX(nome_cidade_destinatario)              AS nome_cidade_destinatario,
        SUM(qtd_produtos)                          AS qtd_produtos,
        SUM(valor_total_frete)                     AS valor_total_frete,
        SUM(valor_total_nfe)                       AS valor_total_nfe,
        _ano                                       AS ano,
        _mes                                       AS mes
    FROM
        dataset_nfe_transportadoras_diario
    WHERE
        ano     = _ano
        AND mes = _mes
    GROUP BY
        cnpj,
        codigo_uf_emitente,
        codigo_cidade_emitente,
        codigo_uf_destinatario,
        codigo_cidade_destinatario
)
SELECT 
    cnpj,
    nome_empresa,
    codigo_uf_emitente,
    nome_uf_emitente,
    codigo_cidade_emitente,
    nome_cidade_emitente,
    codigo_uf_destinatario,
    nome_uf_destinatario,
    codigo_cidade_destinatario,
    nome_cidade_destinatario,
    qtd_documentos,
    qtd_produtos,
    valor_total_nfe,
    valor_total_frete,
    mes,
    ano
 FROM origem
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question. He needed a `INSERT INTO`

Comment: it  does exactly what the user wanted, the insert into is at the start of the query and it works